# python:os.system(r'cd foo') & os.chdir()

Tags: windows, python-3.x, system, chdir

I was having a doubt.When I tried `os.system(r'cd F:\')` I was still in the directory where I started the interpreter.But `os.chdir()' worked fine.I'll show my code below:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('F:')
0
```

By running the `os.system('dir')` I found that I was still in the directory C:\python34.

Then I tried this:

```
>>> os.chdir('F:')
```

By running `os.system('dir')` I found that it worked fine.

Why is `os.system('F:')` not working?
I would be pleased to get a help.

Comment: Could any of you guys please post it as an answer instead of a comment.It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system('F:')` spawns a child shell process (i.e. the `%ComSpec%` shell, which is usually cmd.exe) and changes its working directory. It does not (and cannot) change the working directory of the parent process.

Note that the working directory is not stored per thread, i.e. it's not stored in the thread environment block (TEB) but process-wide in the process environment block (PEB). Generally avoid modifying the working directory in a multithreaded application. Instead use relative or fully-qualified paths.

---

**Bonus Trivia: DOS Emulation**

In addition to the process current working directory, Windows (the C runtime, actually) tracks the working directory on every DOS drive (e.g. C:) in hidden environment variables such as `=C:`. The initial '=' character keeps these variables from being displayed by the shell's `set` command, and it also filters them out of the C runtime `environ` that Python uses for `os.environ`. A bug in the command prompt will show these hidden variables if you pass an empty string to the `set` command, e.g. `set ""`. Or in Python use ctypes to call [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
>>> from ctypes import *                            
>>> kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32')
>>> kernel32.GetEnvironmentVariableW('=C:', None, 0)
8
>>> path = create_unicode_buffer(8)
>>> kernel32.GetEnvironmentVariableW('=C:', path, 8)
7
>>> path.value
'C:\\Temp'
```

Windows *uses* these hidden variables, if they exist, to resolve drive-relative paths. That said, the C runtime [`_chdir`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx) function is actually what creates/modifies them. A Windows program that only calls `SetCurrentDirectory` instead of POSIX `chdir` won't remember the per-drive working directory. Python's home-grown implementation of `chdir` on Windows has to implement this magic. See [`win32_chdir`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b4cbecbc0781/Modules/posixmodule.c#l1398) (3.4.3 source, Modules/posixmodule.c, line 1398).